# How would one be able to assign items a texture based upon their name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently making a mini resource pack for Minecraft 1.9 and when I got to the Elytra I was thinking of making it so players could have a different texture for the item depending on what name they gave it in an anvil. So like maybe when they get the Elytra its whatever default texture I decide to give them but then if they take it to an anvil and rename the Elytra to say... Grass Wings it changes to a more green version of the Elytra.

Comment: Probably not possible without mods if you want the Elytra to function as wings

Comment: @KenzoEngineer Sorry if I was not clear enough I don't need them to function as wings just for the texture to change dependent on the name given to the item by the player via anvil.

Comment: Are resource packs allowed?

Comment: @KenzoEngineer thats what I was looking to make :3

Comment: @BrandonRankin There _is_ a (small, granted) difference between texture packs and resource packs. Sounds and version are the main ones. I think Kenzo was asking if 1.6+ resource packs were allowed, when only 1.5- texture packs were mentioned.

Comment: I think this is possible. For example, when you rename a sheep _jeb or a rabbit Toast, their textures and/or colors change. If this works, then it should be possible for an item to do so as well.

Comment: @ash4fun Well with the new feature in 1.9 to make textures change dependent on durabiliy damage I was wondering if it were possible to make it dependent on item name rather than durability and other misc NBT data so that the different textures would not have to be cheated in nor would it cause players to only have the wings of their choice based upon durability damage. So essentially yes 1.6+ are allowed but if you dont use the new 1.9 format it may be difficult to make happen :/

Comment: @genesis943 Interesting thought but what I'm trying to do is figure out HOW to do the texture change. Sorry for the confusion I'll fix it now :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each texture is assigned to each item, therefore this would not be possible without a mod. However you could make multiple items like "Green Elytra" and "Elytra" if the item you are basing the texture off of has multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it based on damage values. although you'll need to give it using commands and having unbreakable:1b applied to it so it doesn't change textures whilst getting damaged. here's a tutorial I found:

and you can make the elytra function as wings using command blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, but it would be possible to use a command block to create green particles (try HappyVillager) around the "leaf Elytra". I would suggest using a command generator (like "MC stacker") to make this command, and no mods/plugins/resource-packs should be requred for this method. The only problem is that the Elytra *will never change color*, just look epic on the ground.